# Author search on PDF documents

Tags: sharepoint, adobe, ifilter

In my custom search web part, I don't always get the author who created the PDF document. I do seem to get this for Microsoft doc's. Is this a known limitation of the Adobe IFilter for sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, author in PDF via SharePoint search results work fine.

If you have created a custom web part, then you may be looking for the wrong information or it'll be the author fields in the document not getting populated with the information.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I hadn't added the mapped property in Metadata properties. I needed to add owe__Author and now it works. Thanks